# iCal (ics) package for Python

Tags: python, icalendar

Is there some kind of Ical (ics) package for Python which is more "official" than some others?

I just need to generate `.ics` calendars the easiest way possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This one](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/icalendar) is mature and actively developed. Here's the [github](https://github.com/collective/icalendar).

Comment: Recommendation requests for off-site resources or tools are off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you answer them, you specifically reinforce the belief that Stack Overflow is a good place to answer those questions. It is not. Please don't answer these questions even if you know a good answer as most answers will be highly opinionated ("I personally like..."). You can open the flag dialogue on the question and see the close reason in full under the **off-topic** category, or in the [help/on-topic]. You should also not even answer in a comment, as the effect is similar to an actual answer.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I just joined about a week ago, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @Kyll Although might share your opinion, flagging it as off topic is just an opinion. Mine is that this not a recommendation question but an actual question about the Python ecosystem: is there an official iCal package. This is also the kid of question that makes SO pops up first in Google searches. It would have been more interesting to save your keyboard to improve this question or another one.